# MongoDB Distinct Values

Tags: perl, mongodb

I m using this code to find specific text into database then i will load into page with mojolicious.Is this method is good or how fast it is?

```
use MongoDB;
    use Data::Dump q(dump);
        my $connection = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
        my $database   = $connection->test;
    my $col = $database->user;

    my $r3 = $database->run_command([
        "distinct" => "person",
        "key"      => "text",
        "query"    =>""
    ]);


    for my $d ( @{ $r3->{values} } ) {
    if ($d=~ /value/){
        print "D: $d\n";
    }
    }
```

Comment: If it works and is fast enough for your needs use it. You can optimize later.

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` command can certainly work (and it seems that it does), so it's good. It is also probably the fastest way to do this (the implementation just opens appropriate index, reads from it and populates hash table, IIRC).

Note, however, that it will fail with error if total size of distinct values is greater than BSON size limit (16MB currently).

If you ever run into this, you'll have to resort to slower alternatives. MapReduce, for example.